# comparing two arrays elements, in similar indexes with each other

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with same number of members (always)`$userInputArr=array("z","z","E","z","z","E","E","E","E","E");` and `$user2InputArr=array("a","a","a","z","a","E","E","E","a","E");` I know how to find matching members in two arrays. Here I want to find matching elements with similar indexes e.g. if $userInputArr[4] == $user2InputArr[4], increment $matches. In my attempt below, I loop through both arrays but I cannot get $matchs to increment.

```
$match = 0;
for ($c =0; $c < count($$userInputArr); $c++) {
    for ($d = $c; $d<count($user2InputArr);$d++) {
        if ($userAnsStrArr[$c] == $userInputArr[$d]) {
            $match = $match +1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `foreach` be more suited?

Comment: @Script47 I tried a foreach loop as well, with no success

Comment: Nesting two loops into each other here is nonsense. You want to loop over _one_ of the arrays, and access the corresponding element in the other while doing so.

Comment: @jimiss - Its easier and simpler with `foreach` loop. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is the perfect example for the PHP function [`array_intersect_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php):

```
$array1 = array("z","z","E","z","z","E","E","E","E","E");
$array2 = array("a","a","a","z","a","E","E","E","a","E");

// Find the matching pairs (key, value) in the two arrays
$common = array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
// Print them for verification
print_r($common);

// Count them
$match = count($common);
echo($match." common items.\n");
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [3] => z
    [5] => E
    [6] => E
    [7] => E
    [9] => E
)
5 common items.
```

Comment: So relieving to see a smart answer on a bloated page.  No informed php developer would do anything other than this!

Answer (score 0):

```
$match = 0;
for ($c =0; $c < count($$userInputArr); $c++) {

    if ($userAnsStrArr[$c] == $userInputArr[$c]) {
            $match = $match +1;
        }

}
```

You should do like this.

Comment: There is a typo on `count($$userInputArr)` that prevents it working. Also, I would iterate until the smaller length of the two arrays, to avoid triggering notices when the second array is shorter than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$i = sizeof($userInputArr);

 $match = 0;
for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++)
    if ($userInputArr[$j] == $user2InputArr[$j]) {
        $match = $match +1;
    }
```

Comment: `sizeof` can be confused with something else, it would be preferred to use `count`.

Comment: I would set `$i` to be the smaller length of the two arrays, to avoid triggering notices when the second array is shorter than the first one.

Comment: in this case "I have two arrays with same number of members (always)". I made it simple. I`m new on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you. Just use one `foreach`, traverse through first `array`, and check for the `key-value` in second `array`.

```
$s = array("z","z","E","z","z","E","E","E","E","E"); 
$b = array("a","a","a","z","a","E","E","E","a","E");

foreach($s as $k => $v) {
    if($b[$k] === $s[$k]) {
        echo $k . ' is the index where keys and values exactly match with value as ' . $b[$k];
    }
}
```

And Output:

```
3 is the index where keys and values exactly match with value as z
5 is the index where keys and values exactly match with value as E
6 is the index where keys and values exactly match with value as E
7 is the index where keys and values exactly match with value as E
9 is the index where keys and values exactly match with value as E
```

And here is the link: https://3v4l.org/eX0r4

Answer (score 0):

I seems your code not need two for loop increase match in single loop see below code.

```
<?php
$userInputArr=array("z","z","E","z","z","E","E","E","E","E");
$user2InputArr=array("a","a","a","z","a","E","E","E","a","E");
$match = 0;
for ($c =0; $c < count($userInputArr); $c++) {
    if ($user2InputArr[$c] == $userInputArr[$c]) {
        $match = $match + 1;
    }
}
echo $match;
?>
```